# Allow option to delete account in confirmation email (devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-confirmable

I want to allow a user to delete their account in the confirmation email. I've tried this in my confirmations_instructions.html:

```
<p><%= link_to 'Accept this writer', confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %></p>
<p><%= link_to "Delete this writer", user_registration_path(@resource), :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :destroy %></p>
```

But I get the error:

```
undefined method `user_registration_path'
```

Here's my routes.rb

```
...
  devise_scope :user do
    # get "/sign_in" => "users/sessions#new" # custom path to login/sign_in
    get "/apply" => "users/registrations#new", as: "new_user_registration" # custom path to sign_up/registration
  end
  devise_for :users, controllers: { :registrations => "users/registrations", :confirmations => "users/confirmations" }

  resources :users
...
```

I'm not sure what path to use, or if I need to modify Mailer.rb or registrations/confirmations controller. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I think you want to allow user to `cancel` registration and then delete user in your database. Direct user deletion should always require user to log in first, not directly in the email user receive.

Your cancel link

```
<%= link_to "Delete this writer", cancel_user_registration_path(confirmation_token: @token) %>
```

Override the `user::registrations#cancel` method

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def cancel
    user = User.where(confirmation_token: params[:confirmation_token]).first
    user.delete if user
    super
  end
end
```

Cause you have `resource :users` in your routes. There is `DELETE` call to `user_path(@resource)` which fires `users#destroy`. You can use it if you want though personally I prefer first way

Comment: I tried that, but I got this error: undefined method `cancel_user_registration' for #<#<Class:0x007fee07ee17e8>:0x007fee07fbfbd8>

Comment: Do I need to add something to Mailer.rb so it can access the methods in the registrations controller? Or is there another way?

Comment: Sorry, may u try cancel_user_registration_path instead

Comment: it still says undefined method :( but rake routes gives: `cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                users/registrations#cancel` so I'm not sure why it's not recognizing `cancel_user_registration`